# How do I speed up parsing large log files in python?

Tags: python

I need to run a parser on `.gz` files that contain log files for a project I am working on. Once extracted, each log file is roughly `800MB`, and each `.zip` file can contain up to 20 of them.

In total, I would need to parse through as much as `20GB` of raw text files in a single shot. I have no control over the structure of the `log`/`.gz` files as these are downloaded from the company's AWS server.

Within these log files, I need to look for a particular code, and if the code exists within the line, I need to extract the relevant data and save it to a `csv` file.

Right now, I am searching through line by line and as expected, a
single file takes as long as 10min to complete, timed using `timeit`

```py
with gzip.open(file_location, 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_string = line.decode().strip()
        if self.config_dict["log_type"] in line_string:
            log.append(line_string)
```

Is there any way I can speed up the parsing?

Edit: To give context, this is how a single line of the log file may look like

> 8=FIX.4.49=28935=834=109049=TESTSELL152=20180920-18:23:53.67156=TESTBUY16=113.3511=63673064027889863414=3500.000000000015=USD17=2063673064633531000021=231=113.3532=350037=2063673064633531000038=700039=140=154=155=MSFT60=20180920-18:23:53.531150=F151=3500453=1448=BRK2447=D452=110=151

Within this, I am checking for a very specific substring, lets say "155=MSFT" and if there is a match, i will add it to a certain list.

Comment: Depends. 1. can you open this in `'r'` mode and remove the `decode`, 2. why are you using `strip()`? is this just to remove trailing whitespace?

Comment: Can you shell out to `zgrep`?

Comment: You will be limited by the i/o, but you can process multiple files at once.  However, it may be faster if you can throw some command line magic at it.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan hmm there is no reason for using 'r' mode and decode other than me not fully getting why it was opening in binary mode in the first place. I changed the line to open in text mode and got rid of the decode and strip part, but if anything, it made the operation even slower. Strip was to remove whitespaces. (It took ~111s using decode vs ~117s without)

Comment: I'm assuming the `in` part is taking the longest. You need to provide an example on what you're looking for with `in`. You can substitute `in` for something faster depending on the use case. For example, you can use `.endswith('something')` for checking things at the end of a string

Comment: Did you attempt to profile the code?

Comment: Use something like `zgrep` to get only the lines you're interested in and capture the output in Python if you need to do further processing on those lines. If I/O is not limiting, you can spawn multiple `zgrep` processes, or batches/shell scripts to process them in parallel.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan I am searching for a specific substring like "20=X" which can be located anywhere within the string. For example inside a string like "8=FIX.4.49=28935=834=109049=TESTSELL152=20180920-18:23:53.67156=TESTBUY16=113.3511=63673064027889863414=3500.000000000015=USD17=2063673064633531000021=231=113.3532=350037=2063673064633531000038=700039=140=154=155=MSFT60=20180920-18:23:53.531150=F151=3500453=1448=BRK2447=D452=110=151"

Answer (score 1):

I would outsource the work to something faster than Python. [zgrep(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zgrep) exists exactly for this task:

```
import subprocess

search_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["zgrep", "-F", "--", self.config_dict["log_type"], file_location],
    stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    encoding="utf-8",
)

log.extend(search_process.stdout)

if search_process.wait() != 0:
    raise Exception(f"search process failed with code {search_process.returncode}")
```

Comment: Interesting! But for some reason using this method takes 5 times longer to parse through a single log file! Could it be because my files are in a .gz format? But i will take a look into its documentation and play around with it

Answer (score 0):

One example of processing multiple files with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) Pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_log(filepath: str, log_type: str) -> list[str]:
    results = []
    with gzip.open(file_location, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if log_type in line:
                log.append(line.line_stringstrip())
    return results

def process_log_files(log_filepaths: list[str], log_type: str):
    args = [(filepath, log_type) for filepath in log_filepaths]
    with Pool() as pool:
        with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as out:
            for results in pool.starmap(process_log, args):
                for result in results:
                    out.write(result)
```